# Bootstrap modal not dismiss with click function

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

this is my function and my div, when I click the function succeeds but the modal window is not hidden

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnRespuesta").click(function () {
            //alert('entre a btnRespuesta');
            $('#btnRespuesta').attr('disabled', true);
            $.ajax({

                url: "/PreguntasConfigs/guardarRespuesta/",
                data: { respuesta: $("#respuesta").val(), idPregunta: $("#idPreguntaAsociada").val(), idRespuesta: $("#idRespuesta").val(), tipo: $("#tipo").val(), id_periodo: $("#periodo").val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert(result);
                    $('#preguntas' + $("#idPreguntaAsociada").val() + ' tbody').replaceWith(result);
                    $("#idPreguntaAsociada").val(0);
                    $("#idRespuesta").val(0);
                    $("#respuesta").val("");
                    $('#btnRespuesta').attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#tipo option[value='-1']").prop("selected", true);
                    $("#periodo option[value='-1']").prop("selected", true);


                }

            }).error(function () {
                alert('Error desconocido');
            }).fail(function () {
                alert('Error de conexion con el servidor');
            });


        });


    });


</script>

<!-- Modal respuestas -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalRespuestas" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal contenido-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="tituloRespuesta" class="modal-title">Nueva Respuesta para:</h4>
                <h5 id="tituloPreguntaRespuesta" class="modal-title">Pregunta</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="pregunta">Respuesta</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="hidden" id="idPreguntaAsociada" name="idPreguntaAsociada" value="0" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="idRespuesta" name="idRespuesta" value="0" />
                                <textarea required style="resize:none;" class="form-control text-box single-line valid" class="respuestas" id="respuesta" name="respuesta" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="tipo">Tipo</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select id="tipo" class="form-control valid" required>
                                    <option value="-1">Seleccione una opción</option>
                                    <option value="I">Impuesto</option>
                                    <option value="D">Declaración</option>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="periodo">Periodo</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select id="periodo" class="form-control valid" required>
                                    <option value="-1">Seleccione una opción</option>
                                    <option value="01">Mensual</option>
                                    <option value="3">Bimestral</option>
                                    <option value="4">Trimestral</option>
                                    <option value="5">Cuatrimestral</option>
                                    <option value="6">Semestral</option>
                                    <option value="7">Anual Persona Moral</option>
                                    <option value="8">Anual Persona Física</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnRespuesta" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and try with:
$ ('body') addClass (".");
$ ("#modalRespuestas") css ("display", "none.");
When the function ends ajax but does not work

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
$('#modalRespuestas').modal('hide');
```

Comment: @vrvictor Where exactly are you putting the code.  It definately works: http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/unzjakt0/1/  You are using bootstrap 3 right?

Comment: Also, are you sure you dont have an error somewhere before the call? If an error occurs in a block of javascript, execution of the code stops so anything after the error will not be called. That or placing the code in the wrong place are the only reasons I can think of that this would fail

Comment: i'm  using Bootstrap v3.0.0, on console google chrome don't show any error

Comment: @vrvictor Then this codes works. Where are you putting it exactly?